# Time complexity increased by using memoization when I use map<pair<int,int>,int> to store the DP state

Tags: c++, dictionary, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I was solving the [CSES-Apple Division](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1623/) Problem. It was a dp sum difference minimization problem. **We have to divide an array into two subsets whose sum difference is minimum.**

I was using basic Recursion and it worked because of the constrains n (size of array) st. n < 21 and also because elements of array can be as big as 1e9 so overall sum has large value (i.e. < 2e10). So we cannot use dp[n][sum of array].

I have used recusion for this problem

```
ll helper(vector<int> & arr,int size,ll currt_sum,ll total_sum){
    if(size==0){
        return abs(2*currt_sum- total_sum);
    }
    // PICK
    ll v1 = helper(arr,size-1,currt_sum+arr[size-1],total_sum);
    // Not Pick
    ll v2 = helper(arr,size-1,currt_sum,total_sum);
    return min(v1,v2);
}
```

This works fine but I was thinking to use `map<pair<int,ll>,ll> memo`, to store the value of recusion state helper(size,currt_sum) in memo like `m1[{size,currt_sum}] = helper(size,currt_sum)` But it works fine **But I got a TLE**.

Code using memoization:

```
ll helper(vector<int> & arr,int size,ll x,ll t,map<pair<int,ll>,ll > &m1){
    if(size==0){
        return abs(2*x-t);
    }
    if(m1.find({size,x})!=m1.end()) return m1[{size,x}];
    ll v1 = helper(arr,size-1,x+arr[size-1],t,m1);
    ll v2 = helper(arr,size-1,x,t,m1);
    return m1[{size,x}] = min(v1,v2);
}
void solve()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> v1(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin>>v1[i];
    }
    map<pair<int,ll>,ll> m1;
    ll t = accumulate(v1.begin(), v1.end(),0LL);
    cout<<helper(v1,n,0,t,m1)<<"\n";
    return;
```

How can this happen as by memoizing the recusion code I got an TLE? It will be helpful if anyone explain this. Thanks in advance.

Edit: `ll` is `long long int` and **TLE** is Time Limit Exceeded. Time Limit for this problem was 1s.

Comment: Have you run your code through a profiler to see where the extra overhead is coming from?  At minimum though you're doing a second traversal by discarding the value of `find` after the `if` check.

Comment: I have checked on the gdb debugger and surprisingly found out that all map elements are unique. Also used below method but no `Hello` is printed.
```if(m1.find({size,x})!=m1.end()) {
  cout<<"Hello\n";
  return m1[{size,x}];
 }```

Comment: You have to say what a TLE is. That's not a standard term. Google tells me Time Limit Exceeded. So for a start you haven't shown that the time *complexity* is worse; just that it is slower. Also `ll` is not defined anywhere. And you're doing two lookups in the map when one would do. But your code does look correct at first glance. You'll have to actually do some debugging.

Comment: Time complexity has little to do with real world performance.

Comment: (Except when it does)

Comment: Did you try using `unordered_map`?